# for loop to count up to user number

Tags: java, for-loop, count

I want the user to input a number and for the program to output all number up to that number. Instead of printing number in a sequence (1,2,3 etc.) it prints the user number and adds one to it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Count
{
  public static final Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int lastNumber = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter number to count up to: ");
    lastNumber = CONSOLE.nextInt();

    int k = 1;

    for(; k<=lastNumber; k++);
    {
        System.out.print(k);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that is very simple!

You already know how to get the input. Once you have the input number

```
for(int i = 1; i < input; i++) {
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

Put all together:

```
System.out.println("Enter number to count up to: ");
lastNumber = CONSOLE.nextInt();
for(int i = 1; i < lastNumber; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

I hope that helps :) Good luck!